# Getting total count of nodes in tree

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a simple Affiliate System (5 Level max). So basically the database have this kind of structure:

[image]

"**aff level**" column is just extra things so that i know that i listed out correctly.

I have successfully listed out (in bullet format) the parent & child of each agent. Below is my code:

```
function list_current_agents($aff_parent_id, $aff_level){
$max_level = 5;

if($aff_level <= 5)
{
    $query = "SELECT aff_id, agent_code FROM affiliate WHERE aff_parent_id = '$aff_parent_id' AND aff_level = '$aff_level'";
    $result = db_query($query);
    $row = $result-> fetch_object();
    if($result-> num_rows > 0)
    {
        echo '<ul>';
        do{
            $aff_id = $row-> aff_id;
            $agent_code = $row-> agent_code;

            echo '<li>';
            echo $aff_id .' - '.$agent_code . ' - (level '.$aff_level.')';
            echo '</li>';

            $aff_level = $aff_level+1;

            if($aff_level <= 5)
            {
                list_current_agents($aff_id, $aff_level+1);
            }           
        }while($row = $result-> fetch_object());
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
return $count;
```

}

and the output will be like this:

[image]

And now im stucked where i want to list out the total number of the child below if i select one of the parent agent. For example, if i select:

1. Agent1

   - total child : 8
2. Agent3

   - total child : 3

I have tried any method i can think of but cant work out with the logic.
Any help is very much appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create an actual tree data structure and it will be easy to count the children.

Or you can use [one of the many available on Github](https://github.com/search?l=PHP&q=tree&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93).  [This one is even made for you specific database structure.](https://github.com/BlueM/Tree)